# Unable to install appium on ubuntu 16.04 with npm

Tags: appium

Showing below error while trying to install appium.
While doing `sudo npm install -g appium`.

```
npm ERR! Error: Invalid name: "@gulp-sourcemaps/map-sources"
npm ERR!     at ensureValidName (/usr/lib/nodejs/normalize-package-data/lib/fixer.js:284:15)
npm ERR!     at Object.module.exports.fixNameField (/usr/lib/nodejs/normalize-package-data/lib/fixer.js:199:5)
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/nodejs/normalize-package-data/lib/normalize.js:29:38
npm ERR!     at Array.forEach (native)
npm ERR!     at normalize (/usr/lib/nodejs/normalize-package-data/lib/normalize.js:28:15)
npm ERR!     at final (/usr/lib/nodejs/read-package-json/read-json.js:310:33)
npm ERR!     at then (/usr/lib/nodejs/read-package-json/read-json.js:124:33)
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/nodejs/read-package-json/read-json.js:234:40
npm ERR!     at fs.js:268:14
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/nodejs/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:103:5
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-137-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "appium"
npm ERR! cwd /home/mosheko
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/mosheko/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be helpful. Steps to get appium working on ubuntu pc:

1. **Install ruby:** Paste the below command at terminal and hit enter

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential curl git m4 ruby texinfo libbz2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libexpat-dev libncurses-dev zlib1g-dev
   ```
2. **Install linux brew:**
   Paste the below command at terminal and hit enter

   ```
   ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/go/install)"
   ```
3. **set path for brew:** Type: `gedit .bashrc` at terminal and copy paste the following into the `.bashrc` file

   ```
   export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH" 
   export MANPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/man:$MANPATH" 
   export INFOPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/info:$INFOPATH"
   ```
4. **Install node:** Paste the below commands one by one at terminal and hit enter

   ```
   brew update 
   brew install node 
   brew link node
   ```
5. **Install Appium:**

   ```
   npm install -g appium npm install wd
   ```
6. **To start Appium:** Paste the below command at terminal and hit enter

   ```
   appium
   ```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Install Java and check the Java version

Step 1 : Java -version

Install Node.js and npm from the Ubuntu repository.

Step 2 : sudo apt update

Step 3 : sudo apt install nodejs

Step 4 : nodejs --version 
Out Put : v8.10.0 (version of the Node)

Step 5 : sudo apt install npm

Step 6 : npm --version (npm version).

Step 7 : 3.5.2

Step 8 : sudo npm install -g appium

Step 9 : npm install wd

Step 10 : npm install -g appium-doctor

To verify “Appium” installation we can use appium-doctor. For this, we have to install appium doctor using npm.

Step 11 : appium-doctor

Step 12 : Type “appium” into the terminal and press enter button.

Appium will start.